# Formatting Date on Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a String with the following format: january_2005 (MMMMMMM_yyyy)

and i want to convert it to a mysql acceptable date value to insert it on the database.

I need to do it on Java.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably do the trick,

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM_yyyy");
Date aDate;
try 
{
    aDate = myFormat.parse("January_2009");
} 
catch (ParseException e) 
{
    // Error handling
}
```

You can then insert `aDate` into your DB using a PreparedStatement.

If you're not using PreparedStatements and need it as a String instead, then you can just do the following. Although, as mentioned in the comments, it's much safer to use PreparedStatements for inserting into a DB.

```
SimpleDateFormat sqlFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:dd:ss");
String sqlDateString = aDate.format(sqlFormat);
```

Comment: it's very bad using a string to insert a Date into a DB using SQL. You should always use PreparedStatements.

Comment: Agreed. But the question just asked how to convert it to an acceptable value, not how to insert it into a DB. Which is why I provided the option to convert to a string at the end. I will update my answer to make this clearer though, as you're right that it's bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`SimpleDateFormat` API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the pattern is actually `MMMM_yyyy`.

So to get a worthfully `java.util.Date` out of this `String` you need to do this:

```
String stringDate = "january_2005";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM_yyyy").parse(stringDate);
```

If those months are expected to be always English and the `Locale` of the machine where it runs isn't (always) English, then you better need to specify the [`Locale`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29) as well:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM_yyyy", new Locale("en")).parse(stringDate);
```

To save it in the database, use [`PreparedStatement#setDate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29). You'll need to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` first.

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (somedate) VALUES (?)";
preparedStatement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
```

Comment: Amazing how many forget the importance of `Locale`. No one answer mentiones the `Locale`. In non-English machines you would get a `ParseException` on `january` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

First parse the date into a Date object using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html):

```
 Date d=  new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM_yyyy").parse(s)
```

Then insert the date using parameterised SQL (a PreparedStatement):

```
public insertData(Date d) {
   Connection conn = setupTheDatabaseConnectionSomehow();
   PreparedStatement stmt = 
     conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO t (date) values (?)");
   stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(d));
   stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

The question marks will be automatically converted into the correct format for MySQL, and will make your code more secure and more portable. Search for [parameterised SQL](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)
 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Dateformatter...and sue your own Date Format to solve such problems.

[DateFormatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DateFormatter.html)

[DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#)

Please edit your question if errors occur regarding Date Formating :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could so something with [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like this to get a `Date` object:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM_yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("January_2009");
```

You may need to uppercase the first letter of 'january' to get this to work (I'm not sure what range of inputs `SimpleDateFormat` accepts.

Once you've got a `Date`, it depends on how you're storing dates in MySQL as to what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would do it using prepared statement

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMM_yyyy");
Date mydate = formatter.parse("january_2005");
stmt_date.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(mydate.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here suggesting SimpleDateFormat largely look good. However, to (possibly) complicate the issue, note that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe. If this is a potential issue for you the check out the Joda time library, which has similar formatting classes but with a thread-safe guarantee.